# prove this integral identity $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(-x)^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx=(e^{-\pi si}-e^{\pi si})\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$

Tags: integration

**Question:**

> show that:
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{(-x)^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx=(e^{-\pi si}-e^{\pi si})\int_{0}^{+\infty}
> \dfrac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx,$$

where $$s \in R,i^2=-1$$

My try: since
$$e^{-\pi s i}-e^{\pi si}=\cos{(-\pi s)}+i\sin{(-\pi s)}-(\cos{(\pi s)}+i\sin{(\pi s)})=-2i\sin{(\pi s)}$$
so we only prove
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{(-x)^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx=-2i\sin{(\pi s)}\cdot\int_{0}^{+\infty}
\dfrac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$$

This problem is from this Riemann 1859 paper:
:[image]

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem?

Comment: I know,but this problem is Mathematical analysis problem.this students don't know the residue theorem.and can you post you methods(use residue theorem)? Thank you

Comment: The method is detailed in [Edwards' book page $10$](http://books.google.com/books?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&pg=PA10).

Comment: Hello,which book,in china, you link can't open it.Thank you

Comment: Edwards "Riemann's Zeta Function". An image of page $10$ should be [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lT5sI.png).

Comment: Glad it helped @math110 (btw Edwards' book explains in details Riemann's very dense article). Fine continuation,

Comment: @2016: Riemann's paper is available [here](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Zeta/EZeta.pdf) (see page $3$) from this [site](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Zeta/). It appears too at the end of Edwards' book "Riemann's Zeta Function".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that

$$(-1)^{s-1}= e^{-\pi si}-e^{\pi si}$$

And you will see that the result follows.

Comment: This would give a rather unfortunate identity for integer values of $s$.