# prove or disprove $i^{s-1}+(-i)^{s-1}=2\sin{\dfrac{\pi s}{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis,I have meet this follow problem:

> let $s$ is complex numbers,and $i^2=-1$
>
> prove or disprove
> $$i^{s-1}+(-i)^{s-1}=2\sin{\dfrac{\pi s}{2}}$$

I know when $s$ is an integer,this is clear true,But for any complex numbers, I can't it.Thank you

This problem is from when I deal this: http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Zeta/EZeta.pdf

Comment: What is $i^T$ when $T$ is not an integer?

Comment: in complex $\sqrt{i}$ have defind

Comment: Which of the solutions of the equation $z^2=i$ gets the honor to be called $\sqrt i$?

Comment: "in [the] complex [plane], $\sqrt{i}$ ha[s] [a] defin[ition]" Oh yeah? Show me... :-)

Comment: To be fair, there's a preferred branch for $\log$ on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$. It's probable that it's the one used to define exponentiation here (though it would indeed be good for the OP to confirm).

Comment: Is it true that $i^i=e^{-\pi/2}$?

Comment: OP: I strongly suggest to read also the sentence just after the formula, starting with "provided"...

Comment: @chinamath (Unrelated.) Are you user `@math110`?

Comment: There was once a notation where people wrote $1^x$ for $e^{2\pi i x}$, which is even more confusing. This survived for some time in EE texts.

Comment: I have amended my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Write $\pm i^\alpha = e^{\pm \alpha i(\pi/2+2\pi n)}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then

\begin{align*}
i^{s-1} + (-i)^{s-1} &= e^{i(s-1)(\pi/2+2\pi n)} + e^{-i(s-1)(\pi/2+2\pi n)} \\
&= 2\cos((s-1)(\pi/2+2\pi n))\\
&= 2\cos(s\pi/2+2s\pi n-\pi/2-2\pi n) \\
&= 2\sin(s\pi/2+2s\pi n-2\pi n) \\
\end{align*}

This is as far as you can simplify unless you assume that you are using the principal value ($n = 0$).

Comment: "Write $\pm i^\alpha = e^{\pm \alpha i\pi/2+2\pi n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$" Sorry but I would definitely prefer $\exp(\pm \alpha i(\pi/2+2\pi n))$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$... after which your computation collapses (for good reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Because

$$i=e^{i \pi/2},-i=e^{-i \pi/2}$$

So
$$i^{s-1}+(-i)^{s-1}=e^{i (s-1)\pi/2}+e^{-i (s-1)\pi/2}=2\cos\left((s-1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=2\cos\left((1-s)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=2\sin\left(\frac{s\pi}{2}\right)$$

Comment: *Because $i=e^{41i\pi/2}$, $-i=e^{-17i\pi/2}$ So...*

Comment: @Did,so the $s$ have some ?

Comment: @chinamath "so the $s$ have some ?" Is this a complete sentence you just wrote?

Comment: @Did,My problem is from:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834855/prove-this-integral-identity-int-infty-infty-frac-xs-1ex-1dx

Answer (score 0):

Write $i = e^{i\pi/2}$. Then

\begin{align*}
i^{s-1} + (-i)^{s-1} &= e^{i(s-1)\pi/2} + e^{-i(s-1)\pi/2} \\
&= (e^{is\pi/2} + e^{-is\pi/2})e^{-i\pi/2} \\
&= (2i\sin s\pi/2)(-i) \\
&= 2 \sin s\pi /2
\end{align*}

Comment: *Write $i=e^{5i\pi/2}$. Then...*

Comment: Good point. So would you argue the claim is false, or rather dependent on some assumptions about the chosen branch of the complex logarithm?

Comment: Good answer (y)